# Chrome triggering double action on Buy Now Button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On our website if a customer clicks on Buy Now on any of our products (example https://www.nutricentre.com/p-53682-advanced-brain-nutrients.aspx) it adds a quantity of 1 in Firefox but 2 in Chrome. I've looked through the code and cannot see any reason why it would do this.

The code is fairly simple

```
<a class="blue_btn" >
    <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="id">Buy_<xsl:value-of    select="VariantID"/></xsl:attribute><span>Buy Now</span></a>
```

Anybody shed a light on to what the cause maybe? I've tried dev tools and adding a breakpoint but cannot see why its triggering two

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something glaringly obvious, but I'm wondering if the issue is on the backend rather than the front end? Throw in some console.log()'s along your function path and see what is being sent to the backend. Is it a 2 (despite '1' in the box), or does your server receive a '1' from the client and yet it's turned into a 2 by the time the cart loads?

Your '== 0' code works fine, so your .val() is being read.

Comment: It's adding two within the SQL table so certainly triggering it twice somewhere