# Issues with Chrome 34.0.1847.137 and click event propagation in jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, event-propagation

Been looking at an issue most of the day and wondered if any other dev's had this issue with Chrome.

Posted this question earlier ([Chrome triggering double action on Buy Now Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677133/chrome-triggering-double-action-on-buy-now-button)) but upon further review it appears that the error maybe Chrome related.

We have had this code on our product page for 2 years

```
<a class="blue_btn" >
<xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="id">Buy_<xsl:value-of    select="VariantID"/></xsl:attribute><span>Buy Now</span></a>
```

From this morning anyone using the latest version of Chrome and adding 1 product to their cart were getting a value of 2.

If the span tags are removed it adds a value of 1, if they are there it somehow triggers the Buy Now functionality twice.

I went into Chrome Dev Tools and this is the example of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" xmlns:eos="urn:eos">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#Buy_28488').click(function() { AddToCart(); });
                    function AddToCart() {
                        var qty = $('#Quantity_28488').val();
                        if (qty == 0) { 
                            alert('Please select a   Quantity greater than zero'); 
                            return; 
                        }


                        var url = 'addtocart.aspx?Quantity='+qty+'&ProductID='+28479+'&VariantID='+28488+'&returnurl=p-28479-whey-to-go-protein-powder-chocolate.aspx';




                        window.open(url,'_self');
                    }
                    });








                </script><div class="product_pg" xmlns:eos="urn:eos">
```

I might need an event.stoppropagation() call to be made in the function to stop multi click events but this would defeat the object of having a Buy now button.

What puzzles me is removing the span tags seems to resolve the issue. But I am no designer so not sure if I can get around this.

Anybody have any ideas?